# fastest algorithm to remove duplicate consecutive words in a string?

Tags: javascript

Here's what I got:

```
string = 'John bought bought black paint for his black car'
words = string.split(' ')
duplicatelessWords = []
for (const word of words) {
  if (duplicatelessWords[duplicatelessWords.length - 1] !== word) {
    duplicatelessWords.push(word)
  }
}
duplicatelessString = duplicatelessWords.join(' ')
```

It should return "John bought black paint for his black car"

Is there a way to make it faster? I think I will need to use it many times in a row, sometimes on short strings, sometimes on large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```js
const string = 'John bought bought black paint for his black black car';
const replaced = string.replace(/(\b\w+)(?: \1\b)+/g, '$1');
console.log(replaced);
```

I don't know if this the fastest option, but it does a single pass, and replaces only when actually required - so you won't split the string when there are no repeated words.

- `(\b\w+)` - match a "word" made of alphanumeric characters. You may also use `\S` for non-spaces. See also [Unicode support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/280762/7586). The first word will be captured as group number 1.
- `(?: \1\b)+`- find the same word we've captured (`\1`), repeated multiple times (`+`).
- `(?: )` is a logical group that is not captured.
- `\b`is a word boundary, it ensures we don't allow partial matching inside words.
- `'$1'` - once we find a repeated word, like `"bought bought"` we replace it with the first word: `"bought"`.

Note that this works poorly when you have punctuation in your strings.